# How can I freshen the styles and directions in Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I load a list of images in a list . the positions of the  are wrong because the image loading time

```
<ion-list class="timeLineList">
    <ion-item collection-repeat="item in items" ng-click="getDetail(item.id)" >
        <!-- ... -->
        <img ng-src="{{item.customer.photoUrl}}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I need to refresh the page once directives and images are fully charged.

I look for a solution like $(DOM)trigger("create") in jqueryMobile.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to set the `item-width` and/or `item-height` for the `collection-repeat`.

In my image gallery list, I calculate the width by taking the innerWidth of the window and dividing by 4 (for 4 columns). I then take the Math.floor of that and assign that as my height and width (I wanted square images).

My controller has:

`ctrl.calculatedHeight = (Math.floor($window.innerWidth/4));`

With the html:

```
<div
    class="center-box"
    ng-click="ctrl.openMedia(media)"
    collection-repeat="media in ctrl.media"
    item-width="ctrl.calculatedHeight + 'px'"
    item-height="ctrl.calculatedHeight + 'px'"
    item-render-buffer="8"
>
    <img
    ng-if="!media.isLoadingMedia"
    ng-src="{{media.dataUrl}}"
    ng-style="{height: ctrl.calculatedHeight + 'px', width: ctrl.calculatedHeight + 'px'}" />
    <ion-spinner
    ng-if="media.isLoadingMedia"
    ></ion-spinner>
</div>
```

(While loading, a spinner is displayed per picture.)